# If a set is linearly independent, a finite subset of that set is also linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the above statement true? If I have already proven that the set is linearly independent, is it automatically given that the subset is also linearly independent? If so, how would I go about showing that as a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it is true. Call the subset $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. Suppose it is linearly dependent, which means there is a non trivial combination $\lambda_1v_1+...+\lambda_nv_n=0$. But that means there is a non trivial linear combination of the original set which is equal to zero-just let all the other coefficients be zeros. And that is a contradiction to the fact that the original set is linearly independent.

Comment: thank you so much